# Zeppelin fails after loading DeltaTable with "Could not find active SparkSession"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin, delta-lake

I'm running into an issue when trying to do repeat queries with Delta Lake tables in Zeppelin. This code snippet runs without any problems the first time through:

```
import io.delta.tables._
val deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath("s3://bucket/path")
deltaTable.toDF.show()
```

But when I try to run it a second time, it fails with this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find active SparkSession
  at io.delta.tables.DeltaTable$$anonfun$1.apply(DeltaTable.scala:620)
  at io.delta.tables.DeltaTable$$anonfun$1.apply(DeltaTable.scala:620)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at io.delta.tables.DeltaTable$.forPath(DeltaTable.scala:619)
  ... 51 elided
```

I can restart the Spark interpreter and run the query again, but this is a huge impediment to development. Does anyone know why this is happening and whether there is a workaround that doesn't involve restarting the interpreter every time I want to run a new query?

Comment: what Spark version & what is the Delta version?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find active SparkSession
at io.delta.tables.DeltaTable$.$anonfun$forPath$1(DeltaTable.scala:1142)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
```

[here people offer to use the latest version](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/issues/1475)
[here people offer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36905717/un-persisting-all-dataframes-in-pyspark) to use sparkSession.catalog.clearCache() (works in my case)
also, [there is a code example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43024766/what-are-sparksession-config-options) of creating a Spark session